# How to develop an Android application without having an Android device?

Tags: android

Any software simulator that can help to develop Android app without an actual phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An emulator is included in the Android SDK. Check out
 https://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

Answer (score 2):

There is one with the SDK

[Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html)

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, the Android emulator works great, although you should know that it is very slow and it doesn't support some device sensors like accelerometers (although there is a property called hw.accelerometer). However, it is pretty good for testing touch screens, physical keyboards and trackballs as input devices, and for testing compatibility of your app with different API levels and screen sizes.

EDIT: You can also try out the Intel Atom Emulator. You can download it directly from the android utility that comes with the SDK. What is cool about this one is that it is x86 based, so it is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Android Simulator. Even if you have a real Android phone, it makes little difference coz of platform fragmentation. There are cases when your app works on a Droid but not on Nexus One) You can never say.

The whole dev kit is available from developer.android.com

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The Android emulator is totally usable for general development.  And with the emulator you have several release versions in one easy place for testing.  There are a few significant differences that may affect you.  I have never gotten streaming video to play on the emulator.  There are speed differences both ways, where some things are faster or slower on a device, which affects profiling.  The emulator provides dummy data for some services like the location manager, so if you rely heavily on those services you need a real device.  I use the emulator most of the time but always do final testing on the device.  Before release, you should try to borrow a real phone for a few days of final testing.